# Using Python and the os library, how do I tell which environment i am in

Tags: python-2.7

I have written a script, just tested on my local, moved to dev, did not work because of url/environment variable.  I need to add the correct location of the file that is being created.

**how do i tell which env i am in using the os library in python?**

````
```/mnt/www/html/**warkdev**/docroot -  for dev```
````

`/mnt/www/html/**warkstg**/docroot -  for staging`

````
```/mnt/www/html/**wark**/docroot -  for prod```
````

I am testing out

`os.getcwd`

, but that is giving the entire url, and i don't want to start slicing up, How can i get the envir vars info via os so i can tell if I am in stg, dev, prod?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with the same question in the future, use print(os.environ). look for the key/pair that you need then

```
someVar = os.environ['SITE_NAME']
```